# Does my motherboard support 1333 ram?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I recently bought a ECS ECS H87H3-M motherboard, In the specifications provided by newegg.com it supports 1600 Mhz DDR3 rams , It doesn't say anything about 1333 , So I put my ddr3 1333 rams on it , my motherboard turns on but displays nothing (I don't have a speaker to hear beep sound) , So I want to know that my rams are the reason for this problem or I should look for another reason.

Comment: Have you checked the manual for your motherboard?

Comment: You can always check the stats at the motherboard manufacturer to determine if the memory will work. http://www.ecs.com.cn/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1484&CategoryID=1&MenuID=172&LanID=0

Comment: If you don't have a speaker to hear the error beep code you can't know for certain its your memory

Comment: Are they in the white slots or grey slots? It could be that RAM is bad, try one stick at a time in the slot the ECS says to use for one stick and see if it boots up. if so, put next stick in by itself. At least it helps to single out the RAM or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to TigerDirect it does.

> Memory Supported    DDR3 1600MHz, 1333MHz, 1066MHz

[H87H3-M](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8167503)

Some of the supported memory:

- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     Elpida  EBJ10UE8BDF0-DJ-F   Elpida  SS  N/A     Full
  Speed
- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     Hynix   HMT112U6TFR8C-H9N0  Hynix   SS  N/A     Full Speed
- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     KingMax     FLFD45F-B8KG9 NAUS  KingMax     SS  N/A     Full Speed
- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     KingMax     FLFD45F-B8KL9   KingMax     SS  N/A     Full Speed
- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     Micron  MT4JTF12864AZ-1G4D1     Micron  SS  N/A     Full Speed
- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     Micron  MT8JTF12864AY-1G4D1     Micron  SS  N/A     Full Speed
- DDR3     1333MHz     1GB     Micron  MT8JTF12864AZ-1G4F1     Micron  SS  N/A     Full Speed

[Full List of Supported Memory](http://www.ecs.com.cn/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1460&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=172&LanID=0)

Comment: Often is the case additionally functionality is added after a product release.  I suggest the author update the BIOS/UEFI with a configuration that works then update the configuration to the one that doesn't.